# Inverse Laplace transform of $f(s)={\frac{1}{s^{3/2}}}$ using complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, contour-integration

I want to find the inverse Laplace transform of 
$$f(s)={\frac{1}{s^{3/2}}}$$
Refer to the Laplace transform table, and I found that the result is 
$$F(t)=2\sqrt{\frac{t}{\pi}}$$
But I do not know how to get this result. I tried to use the Bromwich integral
$$F(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{1}{s^{3/2}}e^{st}\,ds$$
**My progress so far has been stunted by the fact that we have a branch point at s=0. The contour should be like this, but I don't know how to perform the integration.**

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: $s=0$ is a branch point of $f(s)$ not an isolated singularity (thus not an essential singularity). For $t > 0$ use the change of variable $u = st$ to express $F(t)$ in term of $F(1)$

Comment: thanks for the comment. I revised my question.

Comment: See this.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343764/laplace-inverse/1343825#1343825

Answer (score 0):

$s=0$ is not an essential singularity.  It is a branch point.  Choose a branch to calculate your integral, for example, choose branch $-\pi<\arg z<\pi$ and integrate along the contour that made up of:

1. straight line from $c-iR$ to $c+iR$
2. along large quarter circle to approximately $(c-R)+\varepsilon i$
3. straight line to $\varepsilon i$
4. right half of circle $\lvert z\rvert=\varepsilon$, to $-\varepsilon i$
5. straight line to approximately $(c-R)-\varepsilon i$
6. another large quarter circle to $c-iR$

Can you finish from here?  Be careful when you take square-root.

Comment: I don't see what you are doing. With the principal branch of $s^{-3/2}$ and $c > 0$ for $t > 0, \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}s^{-3/2}e^{st}\,ds=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{ct-i\infty}^{ct+i\infty}(u/t)^{-3/2}e^{u}\,d(u/t)= t^{1/2} F(1)$. To evaluate $F(1)$ shift the contour to the one enclosing $(-\infty,0]$

Comment: This is designed to change from the Bromwich integral to one encircling the nonpositive real axis,

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I revised my question. So the contour should be like this, but I don't know how to perform the integration. Would you like to help me further?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't studied about the Bromwich integral yet but wouldn't it be sufficient to use the identity:

$L(t^n) = \dfrac{\Gamma(n+1)}{s^{n+1}}$

with $n = \dfrac{1}{2}$ and deduce hence?